# The installation of the development version of `dplyr` is not working : "Error: ! System command 'Rcmd.exe' failed"

Tags: r, dplyr, package

**Code**

```r
devtools::install_github("tidyverse/dplyr")
```

**Error message**

```r
Downloading GitHub repo tidyverse/dplyr@HEAD
These packages have more recent versions available.
It is recommended to update all of them.
Which would you like to update?

1: All                                               
2: CRAN packages only                                
3: None                                              
4: tidyselect (190f80d87... -> 87b91186d...) [GitHub]
5: vctrs      (0.4.1        -> 7c9d973b3...) [GitHub]
6: lifecycle  (1.0.1        -> a2666fc50...) [GitHub]
7: cli        (3.3.0        -> 3.4.0       ) [CRAN]  

Enter one or more numbers, or an empty line to skip updates: 
✔  checking for file 'C:\Users\julie\AppData\Local\Temp\Rtmp6lTT4z\remotes399069323c46\tidyverse-dplyr-5f967b4/DESCRIPTION' ...
─  preparing 'dplyr': (591ms)
✔  checking DESCRIPTION meta-information ... 
─  cleaning src
─  installing the package to process help pages
         -----------------------------------
─  installing *source* package 'dplyr' ...
   ** using staged installation
   ** libs
   g++ -std=gnu++11  -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-42~1.1/include" -DNDEBUG     -I"C:/rtools42/x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix/include"     -O2 -Wall  -mfpmath=sse -msse2 -mstackrealign  -Wall -pedantic -fdiagnostics-color=always -c chop.cpp -o chop.o
   g++ -std=gnu++11  -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-42~1.1/include" -DNDEBUG     -I"C:/rtools42/x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix/include"     -O2 -Wall  -mfpmath=sse -msse2 -mstackrealign  -Wall -pedantic -fdiagnostics-color=always -c filter.cpp -o filter.o
   g++ -std=gnu++11  -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-42~1.1/include" -DNDEBUG     -I"C:/rtools42/x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix/include"     -O2 -Wall  -mfpmath=sse -msse2 -mstackrealign  -Wall -pedantic -fdiagnostics-color=always -c funs.cpp -o funs.o
   g++ -std=gnu++11  -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-42~1.1/include" -DNDEBUG     -I"C:/rtools42/x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix/include"     -O2 -Wall  -mfpmath=sse -msse2 -mstackrealign  -Wall -pedantic -fdiagnostics-color=always -c group_by.cpp -o group_by.o
   g++ -std=gnu++11  -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-42~1.1/include" -DNDEBUG     -I"C:/rtools42/x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix/include"     -O2 -Wall  -mfpmath=sse -msse2 -mstackrealign  -Wall -pedantic -fdiagnostics-color=always -c group_data.cpp -o group_data.o
   g++ -std=gnu++11  -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-42~1.1/include" -DNDEBUG     -I"C:/rtools42/x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix/include"     -O2 -Wall  -mfpmath=sse -msse2 -mstackrealign  -Wall -pedantic -fdiagnostics-color=always -c imports.cpp -o imports.o
   g++ -std=gnu++11  -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-42~1.1/include" -DNDEBUG     -I"C:/rtools42/x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix/include"     -O2 -Wall  -mfpmath=sse -msse2 -mstackrealign  -Wall -pedantic -fdiagnostics-color=always -c init.cpp -o init.o
   g++ -std=gnu++11  -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-42~1.1/include" -DNDEBUG     -I"C:/rtools42/x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix/include"     -O2 -Wall  -mfpmath=sse -msse2 -mstackrealign  -Wall -pedantic -fdiagnostics-color=always -c mask.cpp -o mask.o
   g++ -std=gnu++11  -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-42~1.1/include" -DNDEBUG     -I"C:/rtools42/x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix/include"     -O2 -Wall  -mfpmath=sse -msse2 -mstackrealign  -Wall -pedantic -fdiagnostics-color=always -c mutate.cpp -o mutate.o
   g++ -std=gnu++11  -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-42~1.1/include" -DNDEBUG     -I"C:/rtools42/x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix/include"     -O2 -Wall  -mfpmath=sse -msse2 -mstackrealign  -Wall -pedantic -fdiagnostics-color=always -c slice.cpp -o slice.o
   g++ -std=gnu++11  -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-42~1.1/include" -DNDEBUG     -I"C:/rtools42/x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix/include"     -O2 -Wall  -mfpmath=sse -msse2 -mstackrealign  -Wall -pedantic -fdiagnostics-color=always -c summarise.cpp -o summarise.o
   g++ -std=gnu++11 -shared -s -static-libgcc -o dplyr.dll tmp.def chop.o filter.o funs.o group_by.o group_data.o imports.o init.o mask.o mutate.o slice.o summarise.o -LC:/rtools42/x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix/lib/x64 -LC:/rtools42/x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix/lib -LC:/PROGRA~1/R/R-42~1.1/bin/x64 -lR
   installing to C:/Users/julie/AppData/Local/Temp/Rtmp0ADJEi/Rinst523c256932ce/00LOCK-dplyr/00new/dplyr/libs/x64
   ** R
   ** data
   *** moving datasets to lazyload DB
   ** inst
   ** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
```

```r
   Error in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]) : 
     namespace 'vctrs' 0.4.1 is being loaded, but >= 0.4.1.9000 is required
   Calls: <Anonymous> ... withCallingHandlers -> loadNamespace -> namespaceImport -> loadNamespace
   Execution halted
   ERROR: lazy loading failed for package 'dplyr'
─  removing 'C:/Users/julie/AppData/Local/Temp/Rtmp0ADJEi/Rinst523c256932ce/dplyr'
         -----------------------------------
   ERROR: package installation failed
Error: Failed to install 'dplyr' from GitHub:
  ! System command 'Rcmd.exe' failed
```

It seems to be a problem with the `vctrs` package, but reinstalling this package did not change anything. Do I have to install the development version of `vctrs`?

Note that after the line `Enter one or more numbers, or an empty line to skip updates:`, it proceeds without waiting for my input

EDIT : after installing packages recommended in the message above, I get the following error message

```r
Error: Failed to install 'dplyr' from GitHub:
  HTTP error 403.
  API rate limit exceeded for 37.65.12.149. (But here's the good news: Authenticated requests get a higher rate limit. Check out the documentation for more details.)

  Rate limit remaining: 0/60
  Rate limit reset at: 2022-09-10 14:29:33 UTC

  To increase your GitHub API rate limit
  - Use `usethis::create_github_token()` to create a Personal Access Token.
  - Use `usethis::edit_r_environ()` and add the token as `GITHUB_PAT`.
```

Comment: wait a little while and try again?

Comment: Yes maybe. I created a token from Github but I don't know what to do with it.

Comment: I think the API rate limit exceedance will be temporary ...

Comment: It finally installed the library